# How to capture clicked button in js functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to buttons like this:

```
<input type='submit' id='submit' class='processAnimation'>
<input type='reset' id='reset' class='processAnimation'>
```

Now I have two js function. First function is called when ajax request is started and seconf function is called when ajax request is completed.

```
this.showLoading = function () {
     backupsource = $('.processAnimation').attr('class');
     $('.processAnimation').removeAttr('class').addClass('disabled-btn processAnimation');
     $('.processAnimation').attr( 'backupsource', backupsource );
}

this.hideLoading = function () {        
    backupsource = $('.processAnimation').attr('backupsource');
    if( backupsource != undefined ) {
       $('.processAnimation').removeAttr('class').addClass( backupsource );
       $('.processAnimation').removeAttr('backupsource');
    }   
}
```

**EDIT**: Above two functions are working and moving flower replaced clicked button. When request is complete then button is back. Problem is that when I click one button it replace all buttons(class=procesAnimation) with moving flower.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the click event binding code

Comment: Do you bind event handlers somewhere? The `reset` button normally just sets the default values of the form fields and does not do anything else (like sending data to the server).

Comment: Can you show your code for the .click() implementation line?

Comment: showLoadig() and hideLoading functions are called from somewhere else. I asked to work in these two functions to replace clicked button with moving flowe. I am going to edit my question to show you what I have tried so far.

Comment: Of course it is going to replace all buttons with processAnimation - that is what you have specified in your selector `$('.processAnimation')` for it do replace.  If you want it to replace something more specific use #id's instead of classes

Comment: @sadmicrowave: But there may be many buttons on page that required this animation. So all of you are saying that I should go more back and start working from where click button event code is coded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your click event binding I am going to take a quick guess and say that your selector is not set right or conflicts with another element.  try something like this:

```
$('input').click(function(){
     switch( $(this).attr('id') ){
        case 'submit' :
            ShowLoading();
            break;
        case 'reset' :
            HideLoading();
            break;
      }
 });
```

and change the syntax of how you initialize the two functions to the following:

```
function ShowLoading(){
     //do your show loading procedure here
};

function HideLoading(){
    //do your hide loading procedure here
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is using the code u have currently

```
$('.processAnimation').click(function (){
   if($(this).attr('type')=='submit'){
      //submit has been clicked
   }else{
      //reset has been clicked
   }
});
```

but it looks like you should really be using ID's rather than class's

Answer (score 1):

if you have jQuery it is simple

```
$('#submit').click(showLoading)
$('#reset').click(hideLoading)
```

Just two different binding of events.

or did I miss something? :)

Comment: You hard coded here. I want to do this for every button which have 'processAnimation' class.

Comment: Then with jQ `$(':button.processAnimation').click(function(e) {var target=e.target; var type=target.attr('type'); if(type == "submit") {ShowLoading()} else if(type == "reset") {HideLoading()})` Hope the idea is right now :)